# How can I pin a default live tile programmatically?

Tags: c#, win-universal-app, windows-10-universal

I would like to ask the user to pin to start the default live tile when he runs the app for the first time in Windows 10 (Universal Windows Platform).

I know that for a secondaryTile you can use the following code:

```
var result = await secondaryTile.RequestCreateAsync();
```

What is the equivalent for a default live tile?

Comment: Does that apply to Windows 10 as well?

Comment: @HappyCoding  the another question is for Windows Phone 8 Silverlight and this question is for UWP is totally different

Comment: @RicardoPons Thank you for the clarity. I removed the duplicate comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since this question was asked, there has been a new addition to the UWP API: [StartScreenManager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.startscreen.startscreenmanager) in V4 which lets you pin the app's default tile to the start screen.  Here is a Command that lets you do it - and is disabled if the tile is already there.  It handles the Window Activated event because the user could remove the pinned tile manually:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows.Input;
using Windows.ApplicationModel;
using Windows.Foundation.Metadata;
using Windows.UI.Core;
using Windows.UI.StartScreen;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;

namespace Synergist
{
    /// <summary>
    ///     Pin the first entry in the package's app list to the start screen
    /// </summary>
    public class PinToStartCommand : ICommand
    {
        private bool _canExecute;

        /// <summary>
        ///     Initializes a new instance of the PinToStartCommand class.
        /// </summary>
        public PinToStartCommand()
        {
            Window.Current.Activated += Current_Activated;
        }

        /// <summary>
        ///     Can execute changed event handler
        /// </summary>
        public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

        /// <summary>
        ///     returns true if the StartScreenManager exists
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="parameter">the parameter is not used</param>
        /// <returns>true if the app is not pinned to the start screen and the API is available</returns>
        public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
        {
            return _canExecute;
        }

        /// <summary>
        ///     Pin the app to the start screen
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="parameter">the parameter is not used.</param>
        public async void Execute(object parameter)
        {
            if (ApiInformation.IsTypePresent("Windows.UI.StartScreen.StartScreenManager"))
            {
                var entries = await Package.Current.GetAppListEntriesAsync();

                var firstEntry = entries.FirstOrDefault();

                if (firstEntry == null)
                    return;

                var startScreenmanager = StartScreenManager.GetDefault();

                var containsEntry = await startScreenmanager.ContainsAppListEntryAsync(firstEntry);

                if (containsEntry)
                    return;

                if (await startScreenmanager.RequestAddAppListEntryAsync(firstEntry))
                {
                    _canExecute = false;

                    CanExecuteChanged?.Invoke(this, new EventArgs());
                }
            }
        }

        private async void Current_Activated(object sender, WindowActivatedEventArgs e)
        {
            var entries = await Package.Current.GetAppListEntriesAsync();

            var firstEntry = entries.FirstOrDefault();

            if (firstEntry == null)
            {
                _canExecute = false;

                return;
            }

            if (ApiInformation.IsTypePresent("Windows.UI.StartScreen.StartScreenManager"))
            {
                var startScreenmanager = StartScreenManager.GetDefault();

                _canExecute = !await startScreenmanager.ContainsAppListEntryAsync(firstEntry);

                CanExecuteChanged?.Invoke(this, new EventArgs());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Michael, I'll leave the reference here: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/tiles_and_toasts/preview-primary-live-tile-apis-windows-10/

Comment: Thank you very much! I see that running this code requires user's approval "Do you want to pin this tile to Start?" - is there no way to do so without user interaction?

Comment: Correct - user is in charge of their start menu.

Answer (score 3):

there is no way to pin the default live tile programmatically. you can only pin secondary tiles.

the default tile is always available programmatically but cannot be pinned by the app. only by the user itself from the list of apps.

your best solution is to create a secondary tile and ask to pin that. (would even be better to make the secondary tile to go to a specific area of the app as that is what secondary apps are for)

here is a guide on how to implement the secondary apps and how to pin them: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh868249.aspx